# Did Angels sent to earth before Jesus have literal human bodies?

Tags: biblical-basis, angels, human-body

There  are many instances of angels appearing to humans in the Bible.  For example, [Genesis 32:21–32](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis+32%3A21%E2%80%9332&version=ESV)  describes Jacob wrestling with an angel.  The angel Gabriel appears to deliver messages three times: first to the prophet Daniel ([Daniel 8:16](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Daniel+8%3A16&version=ESV)); next to the priest Zechariah to foretell and announce the miraculous birth of John the Baptist ([Luke 1:19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+1%3A19&version=ESV)); and finally to the virgin Mary to tell her that she would conceive and bear a son ([Luke 1:26–38](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke+1%3A26%E2%80%9338&version=ESV)).

What is the biblical evidence that these angels had actual flesh and blood, human bodies?

Comment: Do you want the biblical evidence supporting that they had human bodies or supporting that they did not have human bodies?  Or do you want a particular theological tradition's view on this?

Comment: Biblical evidence to support that they did or did not become flesh and blood

Comment: From variety of religious perspectives

Comment: Unfortunately Pam, that's too broad for this site. There are many different views among Christians regarding who these angels were, and trying to cover everything in a single answer would be too much.  I've narrowed the question to ask for the biblical basis that they *did* have human bodies.  If you want answers arguing that they *did not* have human bodies, we can modify the question, or you can ask for the Catholic view or the Methodist view or some other tradition's perspective.

Comment: If you leave the question as it is, and you still have follow up questions after you get some answers, you can always ask separate questions.

Comment: You can also ask a separate question for "the biblical basis that they *did not* have human bodies" as a way to get both perspectives, if you like.

Comment: I suspect that knowing the angels had literal human bodies would need to involve an angel being wounded, since bleeding or loss of limb would be evidence that the angel's body was real/human and not an image.

Answer (score 5):

How about the section of scripture in [Genesis 18:1-15](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+18%3A1-15&version=NET) where Abraham is visited by our Lord and informed he is to have a son? In the story we read about two who were traveling with our Lord as follows:

> [Gen 18:6-8](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+18%3A6-8&version=NET) - So Abraham hurried into the tent and said to Sarah, “Quick! Take three measures of fine flour, knead it, and make bread.” 18:7 Then Abraham ran to the herd and chose a fine, tender calf, and gave it to a servant, who quickly prepared it. 18:8 Abraham then took some curds and milk, along with the calf that had been prepared, and placed the food before them. They ate while he was standing near them under a tree.

Those who I can see and *who eat* before me I generally consider having a literal human body!

But this, and all of scripture, does not suggest such a literal human form was the [only form](https://bible.org/article/angelology-doctrine-angels) they could appear in. It was the appearance they were to use when visiting Abraham with our Lord. Humanity is bound by God to be flesh and blood but not so with angels.

And to be clear, most translations refer to the two who were with our Lord as **two angels** a little later on in [Gen 19:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+19%3A1&version=NET). They are also referred to as **two messengers** in a few but scripture is clearly identifying them as non-devine (angels in other words). 
     
    Ref: [https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis 19:1](https://www.biblegateway.com/verse/en/Genesis%2019:1)

Comment: You could improve this answer with a reference to the angels that escorted Lot and his family out of Sodom.

Comment: @Pistachio - I could but I do not see any justification from scripture for doing so. [Genesis 19:15-22](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+19%3A15-22&version=NET) states the angels told Lot and his family to flee Sodom to the mountains. However, Lot complained and wanted to flee to a little town and they allowed it. But even in this they told him to “run quickly” (Gen 19:22) because they could not overthrow Sodom (presumably) until Lot and his family were far enough away. I do not know of any scripture that states the angels escorted Lot anywhere.

Comment: I was actually referring to the men who wanted to rape the angels. Obviously they (the angels) were convincingly human-enough to be raped by the people of Sodom.

Comment: Good point! And I see [Genesis 19](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Gen+19%3A1-29&version=NET) also showing Lot, his wife, and his daughters had no problem believing they were human either.